# C++ ATM Machine - A little assistance?

Tags: c++, class, compilation

Here's the complete code for my program and the problem stated below.

This code is from my "virtual ATM machine" program which deals with customers depositing, checking balance and withdrawing money from their account. When I deposit the money, it displays that it gets deposited.. but "customer_actions()" being the main menu for the customers, when I go back on that screen and select the option to check balance, it displays as ZERO.

Which means the values didn't get updated from the previous function. I wana get it to update when the user enters a deposit amount :/

The problem is with the deposit function, im guessing. But I posted the complete program for your disposal.

Thanks a lot guys :)

**HEADER FILE:**

```
#ifndef bank
#define bank


using namespace std;


class bankAccount
{
    public:
        int accNo;
        int password;

        double balance;
        double withdrawamt;
        double depositamt;

        char name[20];
        char address[40];
        char username[10];

    public:

        double checkbalance();
        double deposit();
        double withdraw();


   /* public:
           bankAccount()
           {
              balance = 0;
           }    
*/
};


#endif
```

**COMPLETE PROGRAM up to now:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "bank.h"

using namespace std;
using std::string;

int logincheck (int ,int );
double checkbal (double );
int mainmenu(int );
int customer_func();
int officer_func();
int enroll();
int customer_actions();



main() {

   double balance = 0, deposit = 0, withdraw = 0;
   int atmno;
   bankAccount b;


    system("cls");
    cout << endl;
    cout << "**************** Please select an ATM to continue *********************  \n"<<endl;;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
    cout << "|          ATM 1                  ATM 2                  ATM 3        |  \n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n"<<endl;

    cout << "Enter ATM number: ";
    cin >> atmno;

    switch(atmno)
    {
        case 1: mainmenu(atmno); break;
        case 2: mainmenu(atmno); break;
        case 3: mainmenu(atmno); break;
    }
}

   int mainmenu(int atmno)
   {

   int mainselection;
   system("cls");
   // Menu
   cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
   cout << "|                               ATM Booth: " << atmno << "                            | \n";
   cout << " ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------  \n";
   cout << "                     Please Select option to continue:              \n" << endl << endl;

   cout << "1) Customer Login    : Press 1" << endl;
   cout << "2) Officer Login     : Press 2" << endl;
   cout << "\nEnter option: ";
   cin >> mainselection;

   switch(mainselection)
   {
        case 1: customer_actions(); break;
        case 2: officer_func(); break;
   }

}

    int customer_func()
    {
        int usr;
        int pss;
        bankAccount b;


           system("cls");

           cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
           cout << "|                        AUTOMATED TELLER MACHINE                       | \n";
           cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
           cout << "|           Please enter username and password to continue.             | \n";
           cout << "|                                                                       | \n";
           cout << "|                                                                       | \n";
           cout << "|                                                                       | \n";
           cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n\n";

           cout << "Username: ";
           cin >> usr;

           cout << "Password: ";

           char c = ' ';
           while(c != 13) //Password masking with *
             {
              c = getch();
              pss += c;
              cout << "*";
              }

           cin >> pss;

           //logincheck (usr, pss);


           getch();
        }

/*
int logincheck (int usr, int pss, bankAccount b)
{




}
*/



int officer_func()
{
    int officer_selection;
system("cls");
   // officer menu
   cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
   cout << "|                              Officer Menu                             | \n";
   cout << " ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------  \n";
   cout << "                     Please Select option to continue:              \n" << endl << endl;

   cout << "1) Enroll new customer    : Press 1" << endl;
   cout << "2) Return home            : Press 2" << endl;
   cout << "\nEnter option: ";
   cin >> officer_selection;


   switch(officer_selection)
   {
        case 1: enroll(); break;
        case 2: main(); break;
   }



}

int enroll()
{
    bankAccount b;

    system("cls");

   cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
   cout << "|                          Enroll new customer                          | \n";
   cout << " ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------  \n";
   cout << "                     Please Select option to continue:              \n" << endl << endl;



   ofstream myfile;

   b.balance = 0;
   cout << "Please enter customer name: " << endl;
   cin >> b.name;
   cout << "Please enter customer address: " << endl;
   cin >> b.address;
   cout << "Please enter customer Account Number: " << endl;
   cin >> b.accNo;
   cout << "Please enter username: (ONLY Numerals)" << endl;
   cin >> b.username;



  //generatepass(bankAccount& b);



   b.balance = 500000;



   int genpass = (b.accNo + 10);
   b.password = genpass;

   cout << "\nPassword Generated: " << genpass;

   myfile.open ("accounts.txt");
   myfile << b.name << endl << b.address << endl << b.accNo << endl << b.username << endl << genpass << endl << b.balance;
   myfile.close();    

   cout << "\n\nCustomer Account created! Press any key to save account file";
   getch();

   officer_func();

}



int customer_actions()
    {
          bankAccount b;
          int cust_selection;
          system("cls");

   cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
   cout << "|                              Customer Menu                            | \n";
   cout << " ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------  \n";
   cout << "                     Please Select option to continue:              \n" << endl << endl;

   cout << "1) Check balance    : Press 1" << endl;
   cout << "2) Withdraw Cash    : Press 2" << endl;
   cout << "3) Deposit Cash     : Press 3" << endl;
   cout << "4) Transfer Cash    : Press 4" << endl;
   cout << "5) Return home      : Press 5" << endl;
   cout << "\nEnter option: ";
   cin >> cust_selection;               


   switch(cust_selection)
   {
      case 1: b.checkbalance();   break;
      case 2: b.withdraw(); break;
      case 3: 
           for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
           {
                   b.deposit(); 
           break;
           }    
      case 4: break;
      case 5: main(); break;   
    }

}


double bankAccount::checkbalance()
{
       system("cls");
       cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
       cout << "|                              Customer Menu                            | \n";
       cout << " ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------  \n";

       cout << "\n\nYour balance is: " << balance;

       getch();
       customer_actions();
       return balance;
}


double bankAccount::withdraw()
{
       system("cls");
       cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
       cout << "|                              Customer Menu                            | \n";
       cout << " ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------  \n";


       cout << "\n\nEnter Withdraw amount: ";
       cin >> withdrawamt;
       if (balance > withdrawamt)
          balance = (balance - withdrawamt);
       else {
            cout << "\nSorry you do not have enough money to make this transaction!";
            getch();
            customer_actions();
            }

       cout << "\nYou have withdrawn " << withdrawamt << " successfully!";
       cout <<"\nYour balance is: " << balance;

       getch();
       customer_actions();
       return balance;  
}


double bankAccount::deposit()
{


       double amt;

       system("cls");
       cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------------------  \n";
       cout << "|                              Customer Menu                            | \n";
       cout << " ----------------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------  \n";

       cout << "\n\nYOUR CURRENT BALANCE: " << balance << endl;
       cout << "\nEnter amount to deposit: ";
       cin >> amt;

       balance = (balance + amt);

       cout << "\nAmount depositted successfully!" << endl;
       cout <<"\nYOUR CURRENT BALANCE: " << balance;

       getch();
       return balance;

}
```

The codes that I have 'commented' out are ones I used for testing or ones that I'm still working on, not really needed for now (Y)

Comment: "Here's the complete code" -> `return EOF; /* TL; DR */`

Comment: And when I submit half of it, people say it's not enough code and they want the whole thing :(

Comment: @DinukaPJJayasuriya You have to learn to select the *relevant* parts.

Comment: Good thing my full name is only 18 characters, else I wouldn't be able to use your bank!

Comment: So many things wrong! Both `using namespace std` and `using std::string`. No return type on `main`. Useless local variables in `main`. Mixing of C++ and C I/O functions. Not to mention completely insane control flow.

Comment: A `bankAccount` object doesn't sound like something that should be copyable.  Make the copy constructor private, and then don't provide a body.

Comment: Meaning, I need to go back to the customer menu that allows the customer to select other options such as view balance and retrieve the stored balance in the account

Comment: @DinukaPJJayasuriya:  Then you're [doing it wrong](http://sscce.org/).  Instead of trying to paste your actual code, build a new, small, self-contained program with a `main` that we can compile, is less than 50 lines, and illustrates exactly what the problem is.  In doing this excercise, you'll help us to help you and help yourself by learning more about the language, and you might even find the problem on your own.

Comment: @DinukaPJJayasuriya: You do not need the 'switch' statement in your `main` function, since all the choices perform the same action and there is no default case.

Comment: Wow. Not to pile on, but are a lot of strange things going on in this code. Like the recursive calls to functions instead of returning and looping. Or the `for` loop with the unconditional break. Or the fact that I can't find a code path rooted in `main` that calls `customer_actions`, `bankAccount::deposit`, `bankAccount::checkbalance`, or `bankAccount::withdraw`. For your own benefit you should really review the basics, otherwise you will soon find yourself very lost in your coursework.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your `bankAccount` from one function to another. This can be done by passing a `bankAccount&` as a parameter of your functions, so that the same object is passed around. Your functions modifying a `bankAccount` currently use a `local` bank account that gets discarded when the scope of the function is left!

An ugly hack could be to use a global instead considering the simplicity of your application.

Comment: I'm new to C++ so could you please tell me how to pass bankAccount from one function to another? I've been trying to get that answer all day :)

Comment: The very simplest method you could do this is take out `bankAccount b;` and move it before `main()` - by making it global it will be available everywhere. This would not be recommended for a real application but before you learn a bit more about the language, it should be good enough.

Comment: @emartel: Color me not a fan of teaching newbies wrong methods first.

Comment: @JohnDibling it's a starting point to learn about scopes

Comment: YOU SIR, ARE A GENIUS!! THIS HELPED SO MUCH!! It works :D Oh my god.. Thank god, I learnt that now :D Thank you so much mate

Comment: See, now he's going to make everything globals until he gets fired by someone like me. :)

Comment: Hehehe I shall learn the right method as well in the mean time :) As of now, I clean saved a college assignment due next week :)

Comment: I agree with John Dibling globals should not be taught to someone new to the language.  In my first few college courses for C++ the syllabus explicitly stated that globals were forbidden.  They make the code harder to maintain and harder to find where a bug is.  I would have probably passed the bankAccount in by  constant reference.

Comment: @TravisPessetto it cannot be a `const &` as it's modified by the methods, but yes I do agree with you. I should have been more clear with my "pass your bankAccount" from one function to another"

Comment: @Travis: I hope you refused to use `std::cout` then, since it's a global.

Comment: @BenVoigt ```std::cout``` is a global function not a global variable.  My comment above should of said global variables not globals, thats my mistake.

Comment: @Travis: `std::cout` certainly is a variable, it's an instance of `std::ostream`.